# How to kill a running Spark application?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, pyspark

I have a running Spark application where it occupies all the cores where my other applications won't be allocated any resource.

I did some quick research and people suggested using YARN kill or /bin/spark-class to kill the command. However, I am using CDH version and /bin/spark-class doesn't even exist at all, YARN kill application doesn't work either.

[image]

Can anyone with me with this?

Comment: if you are in a test env : ps aux | grep spark -> get the pid of spark and kill it from command line

Comment: @eliasah "test env", to me the job is already distributed..

Comment: you want to kill a job in production????

Comment: @eliasah Yeah... a job in production got hung due the failure in one host.

Answer (score 272, accepted):

- copy paste the application Id from the spark scheduler, for instance *application_1428487296152_25597*
- connect to the server that have launch the job
- `yarn application -kill application_1428487296152_25597`

Comment: How do you get to the spark scheduler?

Comment: Is it the same as the `web UI` ?

Comment: @Hunle You can get the ID from `Spark History UI` or YARN `RUNNING` apps UI (http://yarn-host:8088/cluster/apps/RUNNING) or from `Spark Job Web UI` URL (http://yarn-host:8088/proxy/application_<timestamp>_<id>)

Comment: can one kill several at once :  yarn application -kill application_1428487296152_25597 application_1428487296152_25598 ... ??

Answer (score 15):

First use:

```
yarn application -list
```

Note down the application id
Then to kill use:

```
yarn application -kill application_id
```

Comment: For future me, one command to combine both of these

`yarn application -list|cut -f 1 |grep "application_" |xargs -I {} -P 1 -n 1 yarn application -kill {}`

Answer (score 12):

It may be time consuming to get all the application Ids from YARN and kill them one by one. You can use a Bash for loop to accomplish this repetitive task quickly and more efficiently as shown below:

Kill all applications on YARN which are in ACCEPTED state:

`for x in $(yarn application -list -appStates ACCEPTED | awk 'NR > 2 { print $1 }'); do yarn application -kill $x; done`

Kill all applications on YARN which are in RUNNING state:

`for x in $(yarn application -list -appStates RUNNING | awk 'NR > 2 { print $1 }'); do yarn application -kill $x; done`

Answer (score 3):

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Application_State_API

PUT http://{rm http address:port}/ws/v1/cluster/apps/{appid}/state

```
{
  "state":"KILLED"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not be an ethical and preferred solution but it helps in environments where you can't access the console to kill the job using yarn application command.

Steps are

Go to application master page of spark job.
Click on the jobs section.
Click on the active job's active stage.
You will see "kill" button right next to the active stage.

This works if the succeeding stages are dependent on the currently running stage. Though it marks job as " Killed By User"