# How to terminate a job in standalone and client mode?

Tags: apache-spark

I use spark-submit to run a job, which has some exceptions, it blocked, so I tried to use `ctrl + c` to stop the process.

1. I would like to know if this job is still running on the cluster on not ?
2. If it is not the right way to kill the job, what's a right way ?

> ^C18/09/03 19:03:01 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
>   18/09/03 19:03:01 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://x.x.x.x:4040
>   18/09/03 19:03:01 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 2 failed: count at xxx.scala:155, took 773.555554 s
>   18/09/03 19:03:01 INFO DAGScheduler: ShuffleMapStage 2 (count at xxx.scala:155) failed in 773.008 s
>   18/09/03 19:03:01 ERROR LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event SparkListenerStageCompleted(org.apache.spark.scheduler.StageInfo@7f6a32f)
>   18/09/03 19:03:01 ERROR LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event SparkListenerJobEnd(2,1535994181627,JobFailed(org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 2 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down))
>   18/09/03 19:03:01 ERROR LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event SparkListenerSQLExecutionEnd(0,1535994181630)
>   18/09/03 19:03:01 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
>   Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 2 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:818)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:816)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:78)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop(DAGScheduler.scala:816)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onStop(DAGScheduler.scala:1685)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop.stop(EventLoop.scala:83)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.stop(DAGScheduler.scala:1604)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$8.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1781)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1290)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1780)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$2.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:559)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:215)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:187)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:187)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:187)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1953)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:187)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:187)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:187)
>       at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.runAll(ShutdownHookManager.scala:187)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anon$2.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:177)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:54)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1873)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1886)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1899)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1913)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:912)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:911)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:290)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2193)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2546)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2192)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2199)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2227)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2226)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withCallback(Dataset.scala:2559)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.count(Dataset.scala:2226)
>       at xx.xx.xx.weekLyLoadingIDFA(xx.scala:155)
>       at xx.xx.xx.retrieve(xx.scala:171)
>       at xx.xx.xx.run(xx.scala:65)
>       at xx.xx.xxRunner$.delayedEndpoint$io$xxx$CellRunner$1(xx.scala:12)
>       at xx.xx.xxRunner$delayedInit$body.apply(xx.scala:11)
>       at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
>       at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
>       at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
>       at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
>       at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
>       at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
>       at xx.xx.xxRunner$.main(xx.scala:11)
>       at xx.xx.xxRunner.main(xx.scala)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:736)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
>   18/09/03 19:03:01 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asking each executor to shut down
>   18/09/03 19:03:01 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
>   18/09/03 19:03:01 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
>   18/09/03 19:03:01 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
>   18/09/03 19:03:01 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
>   18/09/03 19:03:01 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
>   18/09/03 19:03:01 ERROR TransportResponseHandler: Still have 1 requests outstanding when connection from xxxxx/xxxx:7077 is closed
>   18/09/03 19:03:01 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
>   18/09/03 19:03:01 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
>   18/09/03 19:03:01 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark/spark-xxxxxxxxxx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark Kill Running Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565716/spark-kill-running-application)

Comment: what cluster manager are you using with Spark-  local/standalone/yarn etc? Also is it client mode or cluster mode?

Comment: Answer to part2 (If it is not the right way to kill the job, what's a right way ?) depends on the cluster manager.

Comment: @prakharjain standalone and client mode

Comment: with client mode the ctrl+c should kill the job and not exiting the spark-shell

Answer (score 2):

If you are running on yarn you can kill the spark app by below command

```
yarn application -kill applicationId
```

For spark on stand alone mode use

```
spark-submit — kill applicationId — master masterurl
```

Answer (score 1):

The logs above shows that SparkContext was shutdown. This means that the Spark job is not running anymore on the cluster.

Since you are running the application in Client mode, So ctrl+c should kill the application in general.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the resource manager. In my case ctrl+c works fine on yarn, and the job is killed and you still stay in spark-shell. Also you can kill job from the Spark WEB UI or from YARN.

Comment: If you submit with cluster mode, you can't Ctrl+C

Comment: Well it depends if deploy mode is cluster or client. With client mode and jobs running for example of yarn you can. He wasnt specific where the driver is in his question.

Answer (score 0):

When you start the Spark StandAlone Cluster, It's master have a UI on 8080 port.
On the Master UI you will see your application in Running Application Tab.
Corresponding to every application there is a (KILL) option button associated with that.
Just press that button & it will ask you to confirm it. Confirm it to close.
[In the Image, you can see a running application & there is a kill option associated with it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cq0eG.png)

Happy Sparking....